# index(find) + len(find) ValueError: substring not found Crawler Python

Tags: python, web-crawler

Pessoal preciso de uma ajuda para o código em `Python` que busca resultado da internet.

> Python 3.6

O primeiro da `Bitcoin` deu certo, o segundo que apresenta erro.

```
from urllib import request

url = request.urlopen("https://dolarhoje.com/bitcoin-hoje/").read()
url = str(url)
find = '<input type="text" id="nacional" value="'
posicao = int(url.index(find) + len(find))

BitCoin = url[ posicao : posicao + 8 ]
print("Valor BitCoin Hoje: "+ BitCoin + " R$")

url2 = request.urlopen("https://www.ativo.com/calendario/inscricoes/america-do-sul/br/mg/belo-horizonte/corrida-de-rua/36044/park-run-2019").read()
url2 = str(url2)
find = '<div class="row_header titulo_evento"'
posicao1 = int(url2.index(find) + len(find))

Running = url2[posicao1 : posicao1 + 4]
print("Corrida BH:  2019"  + Running)
```

Resultado:

> ```
> /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/system/Documents/Labs/Python/CrawlerPy/Crawler.py 
> Valor BitCoin Hoje: 15186,97 R$ 
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/system/Documents/Labs/Python/CrawlerPy/Crawler.py", line 14, in <module> posicao1 = url2.index(find) + len(find) 
> ValueError: substring not found Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

Comment: Resultado :/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/system/Documents/Labs/Python/CrawlerPy/Crawler.py
Valor BitCoin Hoje: 15186,97 R$
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/system/Documents/Labs/Python/CrawlerPy/Crawler.py", line 14, in <module>
    posicao1 = url2.index(find) + len(find)
ValueError: substring not found

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: acho que isso aqui não esta encontrando nada `url2.index(find)`, fiz uma visita rapida ao site e tentei encontrar esse elemento `<div class="row_header titulo_evento"` e não achei

Comment: Certo, parece que é elemento que não estou encontrando ne

Comment: Solucionado:from urllib import request

url = request.urlopen("https://dolarhoje.com/bitcoin-hoje/").read()
url = str(url)
find = '<input type="text" id="nacional" value="'
posicao = int(url.index(find) + len(find))

BitCoin = url[ posicao : posicao + 8 ]
print("Valor BitCoin Hoje: "+ BitCoin + " R$")

url2 = request.urlopen("http://calendariodecorridasderua.com/belo-horizonte/").read()
url2 = str(url2)
find = '<td style="width: 265px;" width="293"><strong><a href="'
posicao1 = int(url2.index(find) + len(find))

Running = url2[posicao1 : posicao1+1000]
print(Running)

Answer (score 0):

Acho que código `url2.index(find)` não esta encontrando nada.

> **Sabendo que `find = '<div class="row_header titulo_evento"'`*

Fiz uma visita rápida ao [site](https://www.ativo.com/calendario/inscricoes/america-do-sul/br/mg/belo-horizonte/corrida-de-rua/36044/park-run-2019) e tentei encontrar esse elemento e não o encontrei.

*Alem de olhar a resposta do site você também pode utilizar o comando JavaScript para tentar achar esse elemento `$('div.row_header.titulo_evento').length`*